# Python string converts magically to tuple. Why?

Tags: python, string, casting, tuples

I've got a dict in which I load some info, among others a name which is a plain string. But somehow, when I assign it to a key in the dict it gets converted to a tuple, and I have no idea why.

Here's some of my code:

```
sentTo = str(sentTo)
print type(sentTo), sentTo
ticketJson['sentTo'] = sentTo,
print type(ticketJson['sentTo']), ticketJson['sentTo']
```

which outputs the following on my terminal:

```
<type 'str'> Pete Chasin
<type 'tuple'> ('Pete Chasin',)
```

Why does assigning it to a dict convert it to a tuple?

Comment: look at that comma there: `ticketJson['sentTo'] = sentTo,`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You told Python to create a tuple containing a string:

```
ticketJson['sentTo'] = sentTo,
#                            ^
```

It is the comma that defines a tuple. Parentheses are only needed to disambiguate a tuple from other uses of a comma, such as in a function call.

From the [*Parenthesized forms* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms):

> Note that tuples are not formed by the parentheses, but rather by use of the comma operator. The exception is the empty tuple, for which parentheses *are* required — allowing unparenthesized “nothing” in expressions would cause ambiguities and allow common typos to pass uncaught.

and from [*Expression lists*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists):

> An expression list containing at least one comma yields a tuple. The length of the tuple is the number of expressions in the list. The expressions are evaluated from left to right.

Comment: I didn't even know you can create a tuple like that. Whatever happened to the second rule in the Zen of Python: `"Explicit is better than implicit."`?

Comment: Oh, and not to forget `"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."`.. :-)

Comment: @kramer65: you explicitly defined a tuple by using a comma. This has been part of the language from the early days. That you have to use parentheses in some places is.. clearer, but you have to do the same with expressions where the default operator precedence would give you the wrong results.

Comment: @kramer65: Surely you seen (& used) things like `a, b = 1, 2`? But perhaps you didn't realise that that construction is utilising tuples.

Comment: @PM2Ring technically speaking the left hand side is only parsed similarly to tuples (and lists), but no such objects are created from it. So the grammar is similar but not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

`ticketJson['sentTo'] = sentTo,` is single element tuple